# Can JavaScript verify if user is coming from another website or directly?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a question, obviously. Actually, I am creating two webpages using HTML, out of which, first one will be a *Login Form Page*, and if the user will enter correct username and password on this page, he/she will be redirected to the second *Welcome User* webpage.
Since there are two webpages, there will be two different domains, suppose first one is **login.com** and second is **welcome.com**. Now, I want the user to first go to **login.com** and then enter the username and password then, finally, he will be able to access **welcome.com**. But here's the problem is, if the user will go directly to **welcome.com**, he will be able to access his account without logging in. So, I want to know if there is a way through which if the user will directly go to **welcome.com**, JavaScript will verify **(maybe, by using
windows.onload)** if user is coming from *login.com* or directly. If user will be coming directly, the webpage will show error, and if coming after logging in(or from login.com page), user will be welcomed. So, please tell me, is there any way to do this? Thanks in Advance... Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: You should look in to using cookies to store whether or not the user is logged in. However, cross-domain cookies like that are not best for security, so you should keep both pages on the same domain. [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_cookies.htm) is a tutorial on using cookies.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user logs in, browses the main site for a while, then closes their browser, comes back an hour or few later, and tries to browse the main site again? Show them an error since they need to login again? Or do you want logins to persist?

Comment: I don't think this is something you want to do with frontend js though
I think this should be handled on server side and how to solve it depends on whether you are using node.js or php or similar

Comment: You should handle this on the server side. Check for temporary cookie (login token) and redirect to login if not found

Comment: Also, you do not need two dns domains to do what you are trying to do. Both pages can exist in one domain

Comment: Yes, actually, I want the user to login again and again on the website. Sorry, but I can't tell the reason why I want this. I will try to make both webpages on same domain and then use the method of cookies which is commented by Nate Levin, thank you all for help...